# Как правильно оформить предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, грамматика, тире, вставная-конструкция

1-й вариант:
Я не знаю, где ты конструктор этот взял, купил, не купил, но его у меня украли. Так что давай, возвращай по-хорошему.

2-й вариант:
Я не знаю, где ты конструктор этот взял, купил – не купил, но его у меня украли. Так что давай, возвращай по-хорошему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предлагаю такое оформление:
*Я не знаю, где ты конструктор этот взял **– купил не купил, –** но его у меня украли.*

[**Запятая при повторяющихся словах**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=105) (справочник Розенталя)

> **4.** Запятая не ставится:
> **1)** между двумя повторяющимися словами, из которых второе употреблено с отрицанием ***не***, если сочетание этих слов образует смысловое целое, выражающее неполное отрицание или неопределенность в обозначении чего-либо: <...> ***Рад не рад,** корми его* (П.); *Попал в стаю, **лай не лай,** а хвостом виляй* (Ч.).

Выделенную часть можно рассматривать как вставку, которая вносит «дополнительные сведения: замечания, уточнения, пояснения, поправки и т. д.» (Розенталь).
Обособление вставки запятыми возможно (встречается редко), но в данном случае её лучше обозначить **двумя тире**, так как с запятыми графика «нечёткая», на мой взгляд: ***...взял, купил не купил...***. А тире нагляднее показывает интонацию, характерную для данного сообщения.

[**Вставные предложения и словосочетания**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#)

> **4.** В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной конструкции на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, помимо **тире**, могут быть еще **запятые**. Здесь возможны следующие случаи:
> <...>
> **3)** перед вторым **тире** ставится **запятая**, если этого требует структура второй части основного предложения или вставной конструкции:
> <...>
> *Смеялся он мало **– настолько у него хватало чувства такта, –** но всё же насмешливая улыбка нет-нет да и появлялась на его губах* – вторая часть начинается с союза, перед которым должна быть запятая.

**P. S.** Думаю, что между «купил» и «не купил» всё же можно поставить запятую, если мы хотим показать перечислительную интонацию:
*Я не знаю, где ты конструктор этот взял **– купил, не купил, –** но его у меня украли.*

Comment: Можно еще так: "Я не знаю, где ты конструктор этот взял, купил или не купил, но его у меня украли. Так что давай, возвращай по-хорошему".  (Тогда группа будет выделена.)